# Odin installer goes black after 'try or install elementary'

Tags: system-installation, boot, grub, release-odin

I posted this as a [bug report](https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/546) last week, but I'm also posting here to see if anyone has suggestions for what I can try next. Most of the posts here that describe a similar issue (with Hera, eg. [1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25428/install-issue-black-screen-after-grub-splash-with-elementaryos-5-1-stable-2020/28569#28569), [2](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/26719/odin-6-0-not-booting-on-intel-tiger-lake-laptop)) suggest adding `nomodeset` to the boot parameters, but that didn't change anything for me with Odin.

---

**Hardware:** Dell XPS 9370
**ISO:** elementaryos-6.0-stable.20210823.iso

I had been affected by the '[Odin iso fails to boot on lots of Dell hardware](https://github.com/elementary/triage/issues/74)' issue, but with the [updated iso](https://github.com/elementary/triage/issues/74#issuecomment-905901872), the installation medium was finally accessible in the BIOS

However, when I get to the `try or install elementary OS` screen, and either hit Enter, or wait for the `booting in...` countdown to finish, the screen goes blank. The keyboard is backlit, the fans are whirring away like they're doing something, but there's no operating system being booted, no matter how long I wait or which keys I mash at random.

The iso checksum is valid, and the issue is the same across different installation media and I've since tested and installed Solus, then Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS without any issues so it doesn't appear to be with my hardware, or something I'm doing wrong..?

---

Does anyone here have ideas for what I could try? I really want to get back on elementary, but I don't want to admit defeat and just re-install elementary OS Hera!

Comment: I've also had some trouble booting elementary from a USB flash drive. Try experimenting with different partition formats on the flash drive. I think clean reformat as FAT32 did the trick for me, but I'm not really sure...